# Creating a Binary Tree from a list of a preorder traversal with known Internal nodes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

I am attempting to reconstruct a Binary Tree from a given Preorder where all internal nodes have the value  * .  No external nodes have the value *.

The Preorder given in the test case is * * B * * DECA

```
    data Tree a = Empty | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)

    buildTree :: [Char] -> Tree Char  
    buildTree [] = Empty
    buildTree [x] = Branch x Empty Empty
    buildTree (x:xs) = Branch x (buildTree (takeWhile (=='*') xs)) (buildTree (snd(splitAt(length(takeWhile(=='*') xs))xs)))
```

I expect a tree that has the same structure as the input.

I get what appears to be the correct tree, but the inorder is wrong.

Comment: Try writing a function `buildTree' :: [Char] -> (Tree Char, [Char])`, which builds a tree from the given preorder and also returns the remainder, i.e `buildTree' "AB" == (Branch 'A' Empty Empty, "B")`. Then you can build the left subtree from `xs` and the right subtree from the remainder of `buildTree xs`.